# Is every integer a possible year value?

Tags: validation, date, time

I've just been reading this mind-blowing and hilarious post about some [common falsehoods regarding time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time). Number forty is:

> Every integer is a theoretical possible year

This implies that every integer is *not* a theoretical possible year. What is the negative case here? What integer is not a theoretically possible year?

Comment: Interesting question, but not related to programming at all...

Comment: There is no year 0, for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)

Comment: @John3136 Disagree, as it is important to know for designing systems.

Comment: @John3136: You've never written a program that has to deal with year numbers?

Comment: @KeithThompson I have, but I use the system date classes in Java/C/C++ etc. This question is not about those, it is about "calendar theory". Also, looking at the one answer. none of my code has to worry about year 0 - there were not a lot of planes flying around back then...

Comment: @John3136 But I didnt know about the year 0. And maybe I will not be using the date classes in Java/C/C++. And even those probably run afoul of some of these falsehoods. Calendar theory is important (even though this is a trivial case) general programming knowledge

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308542/are-questions-about-pure-calendar-theory-on-topic

Comment: @DavidGrinberg You have a very different definition of "important general programming knowledge" than I do. Polymorphism is "important general programming knowledge", so are scopes and threads. This... just isn't. The built-in date-time classes are more than sufficient for most programmers.

Comment: Aside from the question of whether it's on-topic or not (if you're validating dates, then the answer is "maybe yes; context please?"), [there's a discussion about the linked article on Reddit.](https://redd.it/zckb2) While there may be some good points in the article, [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/zckb2/more_falsehoods_programmers_believe_about_time/c63r2m0) and probably others highlight how silly some of them are, e.g., some programmers won't know how time slows when approaching a black hole (#79), never mind handling the issue while orbiting the blasted thing!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on the context, `0` is not a valid year number. In the Gregorian calendar we're currently using (and in its predecessor, the Julian calendar), the year 1 (CE/AD) was immediately preceded by the year -1 (1 BCE/BC). (For dates before the Gregorian calendar was introduced, we can use either the Julian calendar or the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)).

In a programming context, this may or may not be directly relevant. Different languages, libraries, and frameworks represent years in different ways. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years), for example, supports years from `0000` to `9999`, where `0000` is 1 BCE; wider ranges can be supported by mutual agreement. Some implementations of the C standard library can only represent times from about 1901 to 2038; others, using 64-bit `time_t` can represent a much wider range, and typically treat `-1`, `0`, and `1` as consecutive years.

Ultimately you'll need to check the documentation for whatever language/library/framework you're using.

Comment: The switch from [Julian to Gregorian](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html) has a couple of additional caveats - such as, "for what nation are you checking the date?" According to the Western calendar, the Russian Oktober-revolution took place in November. (Or the other way around, I can never recall.)

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, but none relevant to this particular question. The set of theoretical possible years is the same in both.

Comment: Any negative number is invalid as a year.  In `44 BC` or `44 BCE`, the `44` is positive. There may be calendar systems in which negative years are legitimate, but I don't know of any.  Certainly neither Gregorian nor Julian qualify.

Comment: With respect to ISO-8601 or what astronomers have traditionally used as timekeeping, the answer is wrong. Zero is valid in ISO-8601. You can use it as input year to `java.time.LocalDate`. There is just not a single truth which integers are valid. It depends on the calendar system and/or on databases (some db constraint valid years to range 1-9999) etc.

Comment: 120k reputation and you find '0' an ok answer to an offtopic question?

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Yes, fixed.

Comment: @MeanGreen: It wouldn't have been a great answer, but it would  have gotten the point across.

Comment: Plain "0" would have been plain wrong, though, as Meno Hochschild already pointed out: there are _existing_ calendars which have a year 0, and it's certainly _theoretically_ possible to create another. The answer requires the qualification "...in the Gregorian (or Julian) calendar".

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Updated.